# Can you explain end of line without continuation that just popped up?

Tags: pine-script

I'm creating an indicator and all was well until I saved some code down around line 250 and suddenly started getting this error for code on line 46 according to pine. Here is the area leading up to the error as well as a few lines below it, since it seems to be an indentation problem that I, for the life of me, can't seem to spot.

```
study("Order Blocks and IOF v2", shorttitle="OB/IOF2", overlay=true, max_bars_back=2000)

var color colEntry = input(defval=color.blue, title="Entry Line", type=input.color)
var color colSl = input(defval=color.red, title="SL Line", type=input.color)
var color colTP = input(defval=color.green, title="TP Line", type=input.color)
var int lineExt = input(defval=25, title="Bars to Extend Signal Lines", type=input.integer)
var string size = input(defval=size.normal, title="Label Size", options=[size.auto, size.huge, size.large, size.normal, size.small, size.tiny], type=input.string)

// setup criteria
var bool reqImpulse = input(defval=true, title="Require Impulse Move After?", type=input.bool)
var bool reqEngulfing = input(defval=true, title="Require Engulfing Candle After?", type=input.bool)
var bool reqBOSMinor = input(defval=true, title="Require BoS (Minor) After?", type=input.bool)
var bool reqBOSMajor = input(defval=true, title="Require BoS (Major) After?", type=input.bool)
var bool reqPreBOSMinor = input(defval=true, title="Require BoS (Minor) Before?", type=input.bool)
var bool reqPreBOSMajor = input(defval=true, title="Require BoS (Minor) Before?", type=input.bool)

// tunable settings that won't be in the dialog
var int maLen = 1 // moving average length for trend
var float atrMult = 1.5 // atr multiplier for impulse moves
var int atrLen = 9 // atr length
var float atrPivot = 2 // atr multiplier for major pivot points
var float atrBreakMin = 0.5 // atr multiplier for breaking levels

f_getRads(source, len) =>
    atan((source - nz(source[len]))/len)

f_getHighest(len) =>
    int offset = 0
    float val = high
    for i = 1 to len
        if high[i] > val
            offset := i
            val := high[i]
    [offset, val]

f_getLowest(len) =>
    int offset = 0
    float val = low
    for i = 1 to len
        if low[i] < val
            offset := i
            val := low[i]  // *** this is line 46
    [offset, val]

var float _atr = 0
```

`line 46: Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a bug in pine so nevermind this question. I never adjusted the code in question and simply added some more unrelated code at the bottom as I kept working and this error now magically went away.